# Should you mock key-value stores/aggregators

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, mocking, rspec

I've always been taught that your tests should run in isolation, and other than a db  for ActiveRecord etc., your tests should not rely on any external software/services. e.g. I always mock my other web-service responses but what about responses from web based key-value stores and aggregators like elasticsearch, redis, and statsd? My intuition would be to mock those as well as I am not testing if they work I am testing my apps IO with them. However I see examples around where people uses namespace strategies to test their elasticsearch and statsd related code.

How much should I mock when it comes to web based services?

thanks!

Comment: Here's a relevant blog post: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat them as an ordinary database.

When you are testing business code which uses a database, you mock the database in order to test just the business code (as well as for making tests slightly faster). The same applies to key-value stores.

What you may have seen is:

- Either integration and system tests which, indeed, rarely use mocks. Usually, a system test will run with a database filled with test data. Some system tests may even use third-party web services (some system tests may still mock those web services if you pay per request).
- Or simply unit tests written by a person who is unaware of proper testing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking serves a number of purposes:

- make the test run fast
- make sure all services required by the test are always available
- make sure defects don't make debugging your module too complicated

If none of these is a substantial problem in your case, don't mock.

Why not?
Because

- creating mocks costs time
- mocks induce additional effort when changing your own module's 
  internals (white box testing)
- your mock may lie to you about what the real module actually returns